# Server-side definition of GetFeatureInfo-request parameter for ArcGIS Server WMS?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, html, getfeatureinfo, template

I'm trying to customize the response of a GetFeatureInfo request. I want that ArcGIS Server uses a certain HTML document as a template for responding to GetFeatureInfo requests of a one particular WMS. The other services the server publish must not use it.

I know it's possible to add an XSLT template as a request parameter to the GetFeatureInfo request like "www.mywms.com/wms?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&[...]&template=path-to-xslt-document.xslt", but I want that any GetFeatureInfo response of my ArcGIS Server WMS will be modified into a HTML document without setting a parameter at the WMS Server Connection Properties.

I could not found out how configure ArcGIS Server to do this.

Editing the Capabilities document may be one approach but I don't know how to set the parameters.

Comment: Does that server support queries with `&INFO_FORMAT=text/html`?

Comment: Yes, it does. It is also mentioned in the Capabilities document in the <GetFeatureInfo><Format>text/html</Format></GetFeatureInfo> element.

Comment: So do you still have a problem?

Comment: Yes, because I don't want the default html to be used. As far as I know ArcGIS Server supports a set of different templates that can be used to modify the response of a GetFeatureInfo request. But when I change these files all my services published by this server will use this changed template. I want that the response of one certain WMS will appear like my html document demands without any setting on the client side. That's the point, I want to set a server-side template so the client don't has to add anything.

Comment: Ok, I understand now but I do not know how to do it. Perhaps right people would read the question if the title describes more closely what is the challenge.

Comment: Please **edit** the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: So it appears it isn't directly possible: https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/4822, however as the templates are based on XSLT, you could write some conditional logic to give a different response based on available attributes.